# Effective Embed Range from Sheets to Sites

Tags: html, google-sheets, embed, google-sites

There's this code to embed a range from a sheet into Google Sites:

```
<iframe 
src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/SHEET_CODE/pubhtml?
gid=SHEET_ID&amp;range=B1:G10&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;headers=false&amp" width"100%" height="100%" style="border:none;"></iframe>
```

This code should show only 1 tab, no widget, no header, no sheet name, and it should adapt the range into the site page but it shows only a part of the range:

[image]

How can I make the range to show entirely and adapt to the page? Can also someone confirm that this method updates the embed range everytime a change is made into the master sheet?

PS:
Also found a method that uses into the sheet link:

```
gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&
```

as explained  [here](https://medium.com/@stvhwrd/embedding-a-google-sheet-as-an-html-table-365306d2ec2c), which effectively displays all the range and even loads pretty fast but it doesn't import any cell editing from the master sheet.

Comment: Hi there @Preack ! I get that you want to show the full table, without having to scroll vertically or horizontally. If I understood your issue right then, could you please test using `width="100%"` on the iframe? Please notice how I put an `=` there. Share your findings with us all to continue helping you.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for notice that there was a = missing there.

Comment: Just to make it clear, could you please clarify if that fix solved your question?

Comment: Yes, after adding that missing ' = ' it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was fixed by adding an `=` on the `width` attribute to fulfill the HTML syntax. The final code should look like this:

```html
<iframe
  src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/SHEET_CODE/pubhtml?
          gid=SHEET_ID&amp;range=B1:G10&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;headers=false&amp"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  style="border: none;"
></iframe>
```